# Creating an enumerable by calling a function returning enumerables

Tags: c#

The purpose of the application is very simple.
`PlantList` is a object containing a list of `PlantConfiguration`.

Each `PlantConfiguration` has two schedules: `HourlySchedule` and `DailySchedule`, as well as a TimeZone.

The program reads a `PlantList` object, stored as a JSON file in the settings, and returns an enumerable of `Schedule`, containing all the `HourlySchedule`s, and the `DailySchedule` if it is midnight in a plant's timezone.

In addition to general comments about the code, I am looking for a way to improve the loop. Indeed, using the `Concat` feature to smash together all schedules as they come feels sub-optimal, and I figure this is a good occasion to learn about a new pattern.

```
public class Program
    {
        private readonly static log4net.ILog log = LogHelper.GetLogger();

        public static void Main()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<IPlantRepository, JsonPlantRepository>();

            IPlantRepository serverRepository = container.Resolve<IPlantRepository>();
            var plantList = serverRepository.GetPlants(MySettings.Default.Servers);

            if (MySettings.Default.Disabled == true)
            {
                log.Fatal("Script disabled");
                return;
            }

            UpdateValues(plantList);
        }

        private static void UpdateValues(PlantList plantList)
        {
            DateTime utcTopHourDate = GetUtcTopHourDate();
            IEnumerable<KpiSchedule> schedulesToUpdate = new List<KpiSchedule>();
            foreach(PlantConfiguration plant in plantList.Plants)
            {
                schedulesToUpdate = schedulesToUpdate.Concat(GetScheduleList(utcTopHourDate,plant));
            }
            //... Do stuff with the schedule list
        }

        private static IEnumerable<KpiSchedule> GetScheduleList(DateTime utcTime, PlantConfiguration plant)
        {
            var localDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, server.TimeZone);
            List<KpiSchedule> returnList = new List<KpiSchedule>
            {
                plant.HourlySchedule
            };

            if (localDate.Hour == 0)
            {
                returnList.Add(plant.DailySchedule);
            }

            return returnList;
        }

        private static DateTime GetUtcTopHourDate(int ForceHour = -1)
        {
            return new DateTime(
                DateTime.UtcNow.Year,
                DateTime.UtcNow.Month,
                DateTime.UtcNow.Day,
                DateTime.UtcNow.Hour,
                0,
                0,
                DateTimeKind.Utc
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to create lists and add items to the lists when working with enumerables; [yield](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) is your new best friend.

As written, `GetScheduleList()` is messy to unit test so we can push the condition up a level and then use yield

```
private static IEnumerable<KpiSchedule> GetScheduleList(PlantConfiguration plant, bool includeDaily)
{
    yield return plant.HourlySchedule;
    if (includeDaily)
    {
        yield return plant.DailySchedule;
    }
}
```

To aggregrate the schedules for each plant we can use [SelectMany()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
private static IEnumerable<KpiSchedule> GetAllSchedules(IEnumerable<PlantConfiguration> allPlants, bool includeDaily)
{
    return allPlants.SelectMany(p => GetScheduleList(p, includeDaily));
}
```

We can now revise `UpdateValues()` to something like

```
private static void UpdateValues(PlantList plantList)
{
    DateTime utcTopHourDate = GetUtcTopHourDate();
    var includeDaily = CheckIncludeDaily(utcTopHourDate);

    var schedulesToUpdate = GetAllSchedules(plantList.Plants, includeDaily);
    //... Do stuff with the schedule list

}
```

or even

```
private static void UpdateValues(PlantList plantList)
{
    DateTime utcTopHourDate = GetUtcTopHourDate();
    var includeDaily = CheckIncludeDaily(utcTopHourDate);

    var schedulesToUpdate = plantList.Plants.SelectMany(p => GetScheduleList(p, includeDaily));
    //... Do stuff with the schedule list
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does `PlantList` only contain "a list of `PlantConfiguration`"? Then why bother with a class? Why not pass around `List<PlantConfiguration>` (or whatever collection type is appropriate)?

---

Moreover, don't call classes "Xxxx**List**" or methods "GetXxxxx**List**()". Your code is actually a good example of why: `GetScheduleList()` doesn't return a `List<KpiSchedule>`, it returns an `IEnumerable<KpiSchedule>` (so its correct name would be `GetScheduleEnumerable()`).

Instead, use the word you'd normally use for a collection of items: the plural. Thus: `GetSchedules()`.

---

`GetUtcTopHourDate(int ForceHour = -1)`: parameters should be camelCase.

But even more puzzling: why is there a parameter? You don't seem to use it.

Also, I'm not 100% sure, but couldn't all this be written much simpler?

```
        return new DateTime(
            DateTime.UtcNow.Year,
            DateTime.UtcNow.Month,
            DateTime.UtcNow.Day,
            DateTime.UtcNow.Hour,
            0,
            0,
            DateTimeKind.Utc
        );
```

Isn't `return DateTime.UtcNow.Date;` returning the same?

Comment: I brought up casing and unused parameters earlier.  As for your last question, its not returning UtcNow at midnight, but rather is offset by  Hour.  Hence, UtcNow.Date is not sufficient.  But the return could still be much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things I would do differently.  I think `GetScheduleList` should be a public method in your `PlantConfiguration` class.

The primary method you are concerned about, `UpdateValues` is private.  You declare `schedulesToUpdate` as an enumerable collection, but initialize it as a list.  Given the method is private, I would make `schedulesToUpdate` a list and just use `Add` instead of `Concat`.

You do nothing with `ForceHour` in `GetUtcTopHourDate`.  Also, naming conventions would want it to be camel cased, so `forceHour` would be more appropriate.  Furthermore, it should be a `bool` rather than an `int` with a default magic number of -1.

The logic within `GetScheduleList` leaves me confused.  Again, there is a magic number with `Hour == 0`.  I see you wanting to get a schedule in effect for a certain time.  The `HourlySchedule` is returned always regardless of what time of day it is.  The `DailySchedule` is returned only if the time of time occurs locally from 12:00 AM inclusively until 1:00 AM exclusively.  I would think whatever time of day I ask for that I should get all schedules, hourly and daily, that are in effect for that specific time.

Comment: Thank you. To clarify about schedules, basically, some rows in the DB are marked 'hourly' and others are marked 'daily'. Every hour (even at midnight) the hourly rows are processed, and once a day, at midnight, the daily rows are.